# controller not sending data back to ajax request codeigniter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

I have developed a login system using ajax the problem is when i send the ajax request everything is working and validating fine i just need to pass data back to my ajax request I am using **echo json_encode("true");** but somehow it is just echoing the value true in the controller and not going back in the view!

**HTML**

```
  <form onsubmit="return validate()" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/admin_login">
        <input class="md-input" placeholder="username" type="text" name = 'login_username'  id = 'login_username' />
        <input class="md-input" placeholder="password" type="password" name= 'login_password'  id= 'login_password' />
        <button type='submit' class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-large">Login</button>
    </form>
```

**AJAX**

```
<script>

    function validate(){
        if(!$("#login_username").val()){
            alert("username is required");
            return false;
        }
        if(!$("#login_password").val()){
            alert("Password is required");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
        var data={
            "login_username" : $("#login_username").val(),
            "login_password" : $("#login_password").val()
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '<?=base_url()?>Admin/admin_login',
            dataType: 'json',
            data:data,
            success: function (data) {
                if(data=="true"){
                    alert("ok");
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("not ok");
                }
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

**admin_login controller**

```
 public function admin_login(){
        $data = $this->input->post();
        $status=$this->admin_validate->validate($data);
        if($status){
            $session=array(
                "admin"=>$this->input->post("login_username"),
            );

            $this->session->set_userdata($session);
            //redirect("Admin/contact");
            header('Content-Type: application/json');
            echo json_encode("true");
        }
        else
        {
            header('Content-Type: application/json');
            echo json_encode("false");
            //redirect("Admin");
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you please update your question with your ```console.log(data)``` from your browser console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now iam going to change the code little

change the HTML form to

```
<form>
        <input class="md-input" placeholder="username" type="text" name = 'login_username'  id = 'login_username' />
        <input class="md-input" placeholder="password" type="password" name= 'login_password'  id= 'login_password' />
        <button type='button' onclick="validate()" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-large">Login</button>
    </form>
```

and Now change your ajax to

```
<script>

    function validate(){
        if(!$("#login_username").val()){
            alert("username is required");
            return false;
        }
        if(!$("#login_password").val()){
            alert("Password is required");
            return false;
        }


        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '<?php echo base_url()."Admin/admin_login"; ?>',
            data:{ "login_username" : $("#login_username").val(), "login_password" : $("#login_password").val() },
            success: function (data) {
                if(data=="true"){
                    alert("ok");
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("not ok");
                }
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

and your controller to

```
public function admin_login(){
        $data = $this->input->post();
        $status=$this->admin_validate->validate($data);
        if($status){
            $session=array(
                "admin"=>$this->input->post("login_username"),
            );

            $this->session->set_userdata($session);

            echo "true";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "false";   
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps you. :)

Comment: thanks Nobita! i traced down the issue myself seems everything was ok but the form had the original issue can you explain me simply what was the issue that caused it?

Comment: The problem is, your form get posted to the given action, when the validate() returns true. The ajax part is not get called because you are returning true to the onsubmit="return validate()" so it get submitted.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried sending true or false without the quotation marks?, if not try creating an array and then passing it to the echo json_encode(); something like:

```
$result = array();
array_push($result, true);

echo json_encode($result);
```

on your ajax you will have to read it as follow

```
if(data[0] == true){
    alert("Ok");
}else{
    alert("Not OK");
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: i am amazed myself i look over many blogs it should be done like this but i dont know whats the problem in my case

Comment: Are you sure the information you are getting on the controller is the one being sent by the ajax? because I also see you have method and action on yout html, remove that ( it is not required when using ajax), then try again and check if you are getting the information

Comment: yes that was one part of the issue! but now i have another issue the url looks like this now http://localhost/hostel/Admin?login_username=assa&login_password=asas

Comment: That seems right to me because you are using base_url, and most likely you are working on your localhost. how do you want the url to be? is the data being sent to the controller even with that url?

Comment: na i just want the url to be as it is which is http://localhost/hostel/Admin  i worked on native php for a year and i works that way

Answer (score 0):

you are returning true in the script so the form is get submitted. no ajax call occurs.

```
<script>

    function validate(){
        if(!$("#login_username").val()){
            alert("username is required");
            return false;
        }
        if(!$("#login_password").val()){
            alert("Password is required");
            return false;
        }
        return true;  // HERE THE ISSUE //
        var data={
            "login_username" : $("#login_username").val(),
            "login_password" : $("#login_password").val()
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '<?=base_url()?>Admin/admin_login',
            dataType: 'json',
            data:data,
            success: function (data) {
                if(data=="true"){
                    alert("ok");
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("not ok");
                }
            }
        });
}
```